# error 3780 mysql

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema haciendo una llave foranea en mi base de datos.

El codigo que trato de utilizar es el siuiente:

```
create table usuarios_generales (
    IDusuario INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombreUsuario VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    correoUsuario VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    contraseñaUsuario VARCHAR(300) NOT NULL,
    numDocumento VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    tipoDocumento VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    rol VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    fechaRegistroUsuario TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    fk_IDinstitucion INT(6) 
); 

ALTER TABLE `usuarios_generales` ADD CONSTRAINT `FKinstituciones` FOREIGN KEY (`fk_IDinstitucion`) REFERENCES `instituciones` (`IDinstitucion`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

y pero lo malo es que al ejecutarlo en la consola me sale el siguiente error:

```
ERROR 3780 (HY000): Referencing column 'fk_IDinstitucion' and referenced column 'IDinstitucion' in foreign key constraint 'usuarios_generales_ibfk_1' are incompatible.
```

Porfavor si me pueden ayudar, no se que está pasando :c

Comment: puede suceder que el tipo de dato que declaraste en la table no sea igual al dato con que lo estas relacionando, veo que usas `INT(6) ` en la columna de la llave foránea, pero también en tu clave primaria la declaraste como `UNSIGNED `, verifican que sea igual de tipo `UNSIGNED `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

esto ya lo habia solucionado hace tiempo, pero se me había olvidado colocar la respuesta aquí, el error era tan simple sjsjjs, lo que pasaba es que los dos datos no eran del todo idénticos...

si analizamos bien el id del usuario tiene la propiedad UNSIGNED, pero la otra columna con la que queria relacionar no tenia esa propiedad por lo tanto tiene sentido que sean inválidos de relacionar.

una vez pusimos ambas columnas iguales todo corrió excelentisimo !!

Answer (score 0):

Después de crear tu tabla de usuarios generales, con el siguiente código de abajo vas a crear la llave foránea llamada FKinstituciones, esta línea la pagas exactamente en tu editor de SQL. Lo que hace es agregar una llave foránea la cual conecta la llave primaria de la institución con la tabla de usuarios generale. Solo toma en cuenta que el campo fk_IDinstitución debe tener el mismo tipo de dato y tamaño que el de la tabla instituciones

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios_generales
ADD CONSTRAINT FKinstituciones
FOREIGN KEY (fk_IDinstitucion) REFERENCES instituciones(IDinstitucion) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Sino te funciona o te sigue marcando el error asegúrate de que el campo IDinstitucion de la tabla instituciones sea del mismo tipo y del mismo ancho que la llave fk_IDinstitucion.

Comment: Es el alter de tu tabla ya creada, que no sepas interpretarlo es otra cosa, el código está bien identado, explicación clara de la solución y posible causa en caso de que no funcione. Si no entiendes esto me preocupa amigo